# Writing the string null to S3 file using Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: amazon-s3, informatica

I am writing data to S3 file with the source as an Oracle table using Informatica Powercenter. If the source table has a column with value 'null' ( not null value, but the string 'null'), on writing it to S3, it is converted to an empty string. Instead I need the actual value as it is in the source oracle table. i.e. 'null' ( without the quotes ) in the S3 file.

This issue occurs only when the value is 'null' in the source Oracle table.
Whereas it works as expected if the case of the string is not all small.
For eg: 'Null','NULL','nULL' 
All the above is written as it is to the s3 target. Except when the value is 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

the word null refers to the null value when it comes to informatica. Add an expression transformation in your workflow and check if the value is null or not, if null, then send out 'NULL' inside the quotes directly to the target. do not process this field any more after setting in the expression and it has to go straight to the target for this to work.